# Join two table by one-to-one table when not all keys present in one-to-one table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have `menu` and `action` tables which share links between by one-to-one table:

```
menu: id, name
action: id, name
MenAct: menu_id, action_id
```

Not all `menu.id` in `MenAct.menu_id` set (in other words some menu have no associated action)...

I can't write select, which give pairs of `menu.name, action.name` when:

```
menu.id = MenAct.menu_id AND action.id = MenAct.action_id
```

and `menu.name, NULL` otherwise...

This require nested request or other SQL techniques but I am very noob to Oracle SQL.

Comment: Have you tried `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: @njk Sorry, I am noob to SQL and can't get it right... I always end with syntax errors....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which web-development language is best for a C programmer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723925/which-web-development-language-is-best-for-a-c-programmer)

Comment: @APC I don't understand why you think this question is a duplicate of that one. They do not seem to be similar at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you want a `LEFT JOIN` not an `INNER JOIN`:

```
select m.name, a.name
from menu m
left join menuact ma
    on m.id = ma.menu_id
left join action a
    on ma.action_id = a.id
```

A `LEFT JOIN` will return all rows from the `menu` table regardless of whether it has a matching row in the other tables.  If it does not exist then you will have a `null` value in `action`.

If you need help learning `JOIN` syntax, here is a great visual [explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Finally I get it worked. My production query use **connect by** and **start with** so I surround my query by `()` and put your code around my...